# How to to display the dataframe output of a spark streaming job in a comma seperated form?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am working in python, and not scala.
So my current output, which is a dataframe looks like this:

```
+--------+-----+
|     tag|count|
+--------+-----+
|Apple   | 1233|
+--------+-----+
```

I just want it look like this, on the stdout:

```
Apple, 1233
```

This is the code for the query that returns this:

```
hashtags = allTags.select(explode(split(allTags['Hashtags'],",")).alias("tag")) 
hashTagCount = hashtags.groupBy("tag").count().orderBy(col("count").desc()).limit(1)
query = hashTagCount.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
```

How would I proceed to achieve this format of the output.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to use the str function and print the output.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
l = [('Ankit',25),('Jalfaizy',22),('Suresh',20),('Bala',26)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
people = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(name=x[0], age=int(x[1])))
schemaPeople = spark.createDataFrame(people)

schemaPeople.show(10, False)

for row in schemaPeople.rdd.collect():
    text = str(row.name) + ", " + str(row.age)
    print(text)
```

output:

```
+---+--------+
|age|name    |
+---+--------+
|25 |Ankit   |
|22 |Jalfaizy|
|20 |Suresh  |
|26 |Bala    |
+---+--------+

Ankit, 25
Jalfaizy, 22
Suresh, 20
Bala, 26
```

Please do let me know if your requirement is different.

Comment: So this is exactly what I want, but when I try to do a .collect() anywhere in my code, it always results in an error saying: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();. How do I tackle this?

Comment: Can you open a new question with the error and code ?